# Parse.com - Getting parse.h: No such file or directory

Tags: parse-platform

While following the Parse tutorial here: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/raspberrypi I am getting the following error when trying to 'Make' the sample project they provide.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/parse-embedded-sdks-1.0.0/raspberry-pi-starter-project $ make
gcc   -c main.c -o main.o
main.c:23:19: fatal error: parse.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Open up `main.c`. You're supposed to see `#include "parse.h"` at the top, but apparently the file is missing. Do you know if you have that file?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out. Had to recompiled the Parse SDK - now it works.